# Create Content pane with contextual filter

Tags: views

I am trying to get a Content Pane on a view working with using a contextual filter in a view. The view will only filter based on the URL if I use "Term Name converted to Term ID".  I am unable to use either Term Name or Term ID by itself.

Comment: What isn't working when you name-converted-to-ID?  What  are you trying to accomplish?  Not sure the last time I explicitly did this with a content pane, but that is the normal way to handle terms in URLs as contextual filters.

Comment: I didn't want to use the name of the taxonomy. I wanted the url to contain the ID. So for my quality_type taxonomy, Red has an id of 5. The url I want is /status/5. below is what content I am using which should be the id not the value of the taxonomy. Configure contextual filter: Content: Quality Type (field_quality_type)

Comment: Let me check a site tomorrow.  There should be no problem doing this.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm crazy busy at work.  I need to figure out a site where I did this and double check settings.

Comment: NP I understand.  The tutorial I viewed puts "Taxonomy Term Name" and Taxonomy Term ID" into the fields on the view. I don't have those options. The only thing I can add is [taxonomy name] type field. So in this case it shows me quality_type as an option.

Comment: Actually I just got it working. I am unable to do it with the taxonomy term name but that is good enough for me. If you have the time and can show an example with the term id that would be great.  Thanks for responding!